# Explicitly multiplying values as longs

Tags: java, math

I understand that all math is done as the largest data type required to handle the current values but when you transverse a loop how do you explicitly multiply longs? The following code returns 0, I suspect, because of an overflow.

```
long result = 0L;
List<Long> temp = (List<Long>) getListOfIntegers();
for (int i = 0; i < temp.size(); i++) {
   result *= temp.get(i).longValue();
}
System.out.println(result);
```

Comment: No overflow going on here - just a bug that I'm sure has bitten everyone at least once...  And take care that there aren't any zeros in the list (or that you handle them properly, if they need exceptional handling).

Answer (score 9):

Changing the first line into the following will help:

```
long result = 1L;
```

As multiplying by 0 will give you 0 :)

Answer (score 6):

result is zero because it starts out as zero, and multiplying zero by anything results in zero.

Comment: You might try floating point; it makes all sorts of weird stuff happen you don't expect ;=)

Answer (score 3):

The loop returns 0 because you initialized result with 0. 0*x = 0.

Answer (score 2):

You issue lies in this line:

```
long result = 0L;
```

You're multiplying everything by 0, which is always 0.  Try:

```
long result = 1L;
```